# Stop a running script in python3 from another script

Tags: python-3.x, process, subprocess, kill

I have 2 scripts - one is running and when I press a button, a second script is launched.
That is working; but I would like to kill that second script when I release the button again.

The killing of the second script seems not to be working

below code of script 1

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep 
import subprocess, os
from subprocess import check_call

buttonPin = 5
 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)   #Display no error messages
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN)    # initialize button pin We have a physical 10k Resistor so no pull-up is required

try:
    run = 0
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(buttonPin)==0 and run == 0:   
            print("Button pressed start second script")    
            subprocess.call(['python3', "2ndPython.py"])  
            run=1
            while GPIO.input(buttonPin)==0:
                time.sleep(0.01)
        if GPIO.input(buttonPin)==1 and run == 1:
            run = 0
            print("Button NOT pressed - kill second script")    
            check_call(["pkill", "-9", "-f", "python3", "2ndPython.py"])  # Stop script
            while GPIO.input(buttonPin)==1:
                time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    GPIO.cleanup()
```

code of my second script that I would like to kill when I release the button.

```
import time
from time import sleep 

def main():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count = count +1
       # do whatever the script does
        print("You have started this program X " + str(count) + " times now")
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can't seem to find why the second script is not killed.

Comment: `call` blocks until the subprocess exits; your program only regains control after that.

Comment: Anyway, running Python as a subprocess of itself is often an antipattern. You should probably refactor to `import` and run the `main` function in the current process.